# How to kill a running thread in wait?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait

When i try to kill my Robber threads, some die , but some get stuck in the wait() block , what would be a better way to kill all the threads , or how do i get the blocked threads out to be killed?

```
private int robberId;
private static int robberGlobalId=0;
private TreasureChest chest;
private boolean alive = true;

public Robber(TreasureChest chest) {
    robberId = robberGlobalId;
    robberGlobalId++;

    this.chest = chest;
}

public void run() {
    while (alive) {
        try {
            synchronized(chest){
                robCoin();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Robber " +robberId +" just died");
}

public void robCoin() throws InterruptedException {
    if (chest.getTreasureAmount() <= 0 ) {
        chest.wait();
    } else { 
        chest.removeCoin();
    }
    Thread.sleep(50);
}

public void killRobber() {
    alive = false;
}
```

Comment: http://arashmd.blogspot.com/2013/06/java-threading.html#shuttr

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> When i try to kill my Robber threads, some die , but some get stuck in the wait() block , what would be a better way to kill all the threads ,

The right way to "kill" a thread is to interrupt it with `thread.interrupt()`.  If the thread is blocked in a `wait(...)` call, this will immediately throw `InterruptedException`.  When you catch  `InterruptedException` it is a good idea to immediately re-interrupt the thread to preserve the interrupt flag because when the exception is thrown, the interrupt bit is cleared.

```
try {
    ...wait();
} catch (InterruptedException ie) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    // handle the interrupt
    return;
}
```

Since not all methods throw `InterruptedException`, you can also check to make sure the thread has been interrupted with something like the following:

```
if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
    // stop processing
    return;
}
```

Or in your case something like:

```
while (alive && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
```

Btw, `alive` should be `volatile` because it looks to be accessed by multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

Interrupting the thread is one way to do it as demonstrated in @Gray's answer, however it might be cleaner to wake up waiting threads when you "kill" the Robber instead of interrupting them.

In this example below the "Robber task" (implemented by the `run()` method) will wait as long as the robber is alive and the chest is empty ( less than or equal to 0). If `killRobber()` is called waiting threads are woken up and exit `run()` gracefully (alive will be `false`).

```
public void run() {
    try{
        synchronized(chest){
            while (chest.getTreasureAmount() <= 0 && alive) {
                chest.wait();
            } 
            if(alive){
                chest.removeCoin();
            }
        }
    }catch (InterruptedException ie){
        /* Thread interrupted do something appropriate,
           which may be to do nothing */
    }
}

public void killRobber() {
    synchronized(chest){
        alive = false;
        chest.notifyAll();
    }
}
```